# how to implement facebook share for chrome extension

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create a chrome extension where user will share current tab url via facebook.I am trying to use facebook javascript sdk.When I call the share dialogue it says

```
 Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

I know that on the facebook app I have to set the site url.But its a chrome extension.So what will be the site url or how to solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [share on facebook from chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283842/share-on-facebook-from-chrome-extension)

Comment: @BlackJack did you have any luck with this? I'm running in to the same problem.